# How can i add a row vector in a tibble in R?

Tags: r, tidyverse, addition

I have a tibble in R that has 11 observations of every month.Apart from June that has 0.
My data frame (tibble) looks like this :

```
library(tidyverse)
A = c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12)
B = rnorm(11,0,1)
Data = tibble(A,B);Data
```

But i want to add the 0 observation of June of this timeseries.
Something like :

```
d = c(6,0);d
newdata = rbind(Data,d)
order(newdata$A)
```

but the 12 (december) appears.Any help?

Comment: How about using `tidyr::complete(Data, A = seq(min(A), max(A)), fill = list(B = 0))` ?

Comment: Read help for order. It is not what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

(1) We can use `add_row` for this. However, `d` must be named and we need to splice it into `add_row` with the tribble bang `!!!` operator. Then we can `arrange` the data so that the month are sorted from 1 to 12. Of course you can specify `add_row` directly like in @Chris answer without the need of an external vector.

```r
library(dplyr)

A = c(1,2,3,4,5,7,8,9,10,11,12)
B = rnorm(11,0,1)
Data = tibble(A,B)

d = c(A = 6, B = 0)

newdata <- Data %>% 
  add_row(!!! d) %>% 
  arrange(A)

# check
newdata
#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>        A        B
#>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1     1  1.22   
#>  2     2  0.0729 
#>  3     3  0.597  
#>  4     4 -1.26   
#>  5     5  0.928  
#>  6     6  0      
#>  7     7 -1.08   
#>  8     8  0.704  
#>  9     9 -0.119  
#> 10    10 -0.462  
#> 11    11 -0.00388
#> 12    12  1.56

order(newdata$A) 
#>  [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12
```

(2) We can use `tidyr::complete`, as suggested by @Ronak in the comments, although we use a slightly different specification with `full_seq`:

```r
library(tidyr)

Data %>% 
  complete(A = full_seq(A, 1), fill = list(B = 0))

#> # A tibble: 12 x 2
#>        A      B
#>    <dbl>  <dbl>
#>  1     1 -0.258
#>  2     2 -1.18 
#>  3     3 -0.165
#>  4     4  0.775
#>  5     5  0.926
#>  6     6  0    
#>  7     7  0.343
#>  8     8  1.10 
#>  9     9  0.359
#> 10    10  0.934
#> 11    11 -0.444
#> 12    12  0.184
```

<sup>Created on 2021-09-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Again when i `order(newdata$A)` the problem remains

Comment: @NikosTsiantakis: Please see my updated answer including your check. I'm using dplyr 1.0.7 and R 4.1.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the additional row in `add_row`:

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
  add_row(A = 6, B = 0) %>% 
  arrange(A)
# A tibble: 12 x 2
       A       B
   <dbl>   <dbl>
 1     1 -0.547 
 2     2 -0.564 
 3     3 -0.890 
 4     4 -0.477 
 5     5 -0.998 
 6     6  0     
 7     7 -0.776 
 8     8  0.0645
 9     9  0.959 
10    10 -0.110 
11    11 -0.511 
12    12 -0.911
```

Comment: can i avoid this addition , by using the complete function somehow ?

Comment: Not sure I understand. The best, most concise, solution is Ronak's, which uses `complete`, namely: `tidyr::complete(Data, A = seq(min(A), max(A)), fill = list(B = 0))`- Have you tried it?

Comment: YES IT WORKED BUT I HOPED TO AVOID IT